# Refresh a sql connection file using a single button

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, office-automation

I am trying to record a macro to refresh a sql connection file using a single button in vba but it comes up with an error. On hitting the refresh button to which I have assigned the macro, it says

> Run time error 91 - You attempted to use an object variable that isn't yet referencing a valid object.

```
Sub RefreshCRS610()
'
' RefreshCRS610 Macro
'

'
    With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable
        .Connection = Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=FDReport;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=FDReport;Initial Catalog=M6FDBGRP;Data Source=mlirvcb00" _
        , _
        "1;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=FXV10084;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag w" _
        , "ith column collation when possible=False")
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT DISTINCT OKCONO As 'Company Number', OKCUNO As 'Customer Number', OKSTAT As 'Status', OKRESP As 'Branch Resp" _
        , "onsible' FROM M6FDBGRP.MPXFDTA.OCUSMA")
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I was trying to automate refreshing the sql connection table without hitting right click-> edit query->table->okay-> enter pwd again and again. Trying to just refresh the azure sql database table by one click.

Comment: Did you try to run the code under the debugger attached? Which line of code exactly gives the error?

Comment: "With Selection.ListObject.QueryTable" comes up with an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Run time error 91 - You attempted to use an object variable that isn't yet referencing a valid object.

Try getting the valid `Selection` object instance from the `Application` or `ActiveWorksheet` instances.